# applying sed to certains line from file using bash

Tags: bash, sed, find

I need you help on this; 
I am currently trying to apply a sed command to lines from a file.

```
2014-08-05T09:29:13+01:00 (INFO:3824.87075728): [27219] [ <email@domain.com>] A message from <user1@domain.com> source <asdfg> this is a test.
```

I need to apply this sed cmd to this line but keep this others that does not have 'this is a test'

```
pattern="this\ is\ a test"
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *"${pattern}"* ]]; then
        sed 's/\[ .*\(source\)/\1/g' ${line}

else
    echo "${line}"
fi
done < ${INPUT} > ${OUPUT}
```

I have set the input and output; however ideally keeping the same file would be ideal.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this. Use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/this is a test/s/\[ .*\(source\)/\1/g' "${INPUT}"
```